# Change pdf files with the Poppler library

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, poppler

Not so long ago I started working with the Poppler library. Learned how to get data from a pdf file. But the question is that I need to modify this file. For example, add a new blank page and save it as a PDF. On the Internet, it is mainly described how to get data, but not make changes to the file.

Comment: A quick browse through the [libpoppler API documentation](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/api/qt5/annotated.html) does not reveal any obvious methods for adding pages. So the answer is "you will need a different library".

Comment: Ок. It turns out that you can't even add your own image to an existing page?

Answer (score 1):

The OP has recognized there are no creative features in the poppler utilities library (which are a spin off from xpdf utilities)

Xpdf PDF file viewer widget and family do have some modify pdf abilities but as part of a wider suite of QT applications.

Poppler is aligned with Cairo which is designed to produce consistent output on all output media. However editing/altering PDFs is not its aim.

You can use poppler to achieve the requested task in a roundabout fashion, but it's very limited for similar tasks or content editing.

The direct answer to the question is to use poppler to split the source

so for example to add in a blank page 3 into a 3 page source (thus pushing existing page 3 to 4)

```
pdfseparate.exe -f 1 -l 2 layout.pdf page%d.pdf
pdfseparate.exe -f 3 -l 3 layout.pdf page4.pdf
pdfunite.exe page1.pdf page2.pdf inserted.pdf page4.pdf newlayout.pdf
```

However this is ***NOT a recommended method*** as many similar related issues will be found in Q&A, since the new file is usually bloated by duplicated resources, and much of the internal links in the source suffer collateral damage.

For this task a more dedicated manipulation app is required such as say cpdf